# TypeORM count grouping with different left joins each time

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using NestJS with TypeORM and PostgreSQL. I have a queryBuilder which joins other tables based on the provided array of relations.

```
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user');

if (relations.includes('relation1') {
  query.leftJoinAndSelect('user.relation1', 'r1');
}
if (relations.includes('relation2') {
  query.leftJoinAndSelect('user.relation2', 'r2');
}
if (relations.includes('relation3') {
  query.leftJoinAndSelect('user.relation3', 'r3');
}

// 6 more relations
```

Following that I select a count on another table.

```
query
.leftJoin('user.relation4', 'r4')
.addSelect('COUNT(case when r4.value > 10 then r4.id end', 'user_moreThan')
.addSelect('COUNT(case when r4.value < 10 then r4.id end', 'user_lessThan')
.groupBy('user.id, r1.id, r2.id, r3.id ...')
```

And lastly I use one of the counts (depending on the request) for ordering the result with orderBy.

Now, of course, based on the relations parameter, the requirements for the groupBy query change. If I join all tables, TypeORM expects all of them to be present in groupBy.

I initially had the count query separated, but that was before I wanted to use the result for ordering.

Right now I planned to just dynamically create the groupBy string, but this approach somehow feels wrong and I am wondering if it is in fact the way to go or if there is a better approach to achieving what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add group by clause conditionally -

```
if (relations.includes('relation1') {
  query.addGroupBy('r1.id');
}
```

Comment: Hi, yep, I already know that. I was also wondering if this approach makes sense at all or is there another better way of structuring the query to achieve the same result.